# nodejs, sails: creating 2 records of different model at same time

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have 2 models called `users` and `books` with one to many associations. My schema looks like

**1. model user.js**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    userName: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    books: {
      type: 'ref',
      columnType: 'book',
      via: 'userBooks'
    }
```

**book.js model**

```
attributes: {
    bookName: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    userBooks: {
      model: 'user'
    }
```

A user may contains any number of books,
I am adding fields of books under user create form, on clicking submit button I need to create records in both user table and book table. Can anyone help me how we can handle the same in controller. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create yours books with a bulk create, then get the id of yours books and finally create your user.

```
var books = await Book.createEach(req.param('books')).fetch();
if(books){
     var ids = books.map(b => b.id); //get all the id attribute from book object
     var user = await User.create({ userName: req.param('userName'), books: ids});
}
```

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/fetch
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create-each
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map